# Conditionally showing options in a select with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I am creating a template for showing Select fields in my app. However I have 4 different types of select field. value = id, value = name, value = static_id and value = static_name (it's complicated...).

I plan to migrate these to ngOptions if possible in the future, but for now I am attempting to have a single select template, that will handle all 4 types of field.

I currently use an ng-if to show the different 'static' code for a select, but this creates a lot of code that I want to reduce into this single template.

Here's some code:

```
// shows a basic select field where option value = id
<div ng-if="field.type=='select'" class="form-group">
    <select-field></select-field>
</div>

// shows a basic select field where option value = name
<div ng-if="field.type=='select_name'" class="form-group">
    <select-field></select-field>
</div>

// shows a basic select field where option value = static_id
<div ng-if="field.type=='select_static_id'" class="form-group">
    <select-field></select-field>
</div>

// shows a basic select field where option value = static_name
<div ng-if="field.type=='select_static_name'" class="form-group">
    <select-field></select-field>
</div>
```

Here, all the field attributes are identical, except for the generated options. Hence why I want to template this.

I am attempting to have this single template have another ng-if inside that will detect the field type, from the JSON it reads, and then change the options displayed accordingly, like this (2 of the 4 examples shown):

```
<select 
    name={{field.name}} 
    class="form-control form-field {{relationshipUrl}}"
    id={{field.name}} 
    data-is-autofocus={{field.focus}} 
    data-selectreq={{field.rules.selectreq}} 
    data-showhide={{field.rules.showhide}}
>
    <option value="" selected>Please select...</option>
    <span ng-if="field.type=='select'">     
        <option 
            value={{option.id}} 
            ng-repeat="option in cache[field.relationshipURL] | orderBy:'name || firstName'" 
            ng-selected="formData[field.name] == option.id">
                {{option.name || option.firstName}}
        </option>
    </span>
    <span ng-if="field.type=='select_static_name'">
        <option 
            value={{option.name}} 
            ng-repeat="option in cache[field.relationshipURL] | orderBy:'name'"
            ng-selected="formData[field.name] == option.name">
                {{option.name}}
        </option>
    </span>
</select>
```

Possibly horrible code to use a span within the select, but that's why I am coming to you good people. Currently this works in that it shows the correct options, however, it shows the options listed out twice, and I assume it will list them 4 times once all the option types are included. I hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's invalid html. Can really only have 2 tags in a select ... `<option>` and `<optgroup>`. It might be working in one browser you are using...but don't count on it working cross browser. Different browsers have different tolerances to invalid markup and handle it differently. Would almost guarantee this breaks in IE

Comment: better approach would be to filter ng-options

Answer (score 0):

Well no sooner had I posted, the answer was blindingly obvious. Instead of the above approach by removing the span and putting the ng-if on the `<option>` instead fixed the issue and it works perfectly!

```
<select 
    name={{field.name}} 
    class="form-control form-field {{relationshipUrl}}"
    id={{field.name}} 
    data-is-autofocus={{field.focus}} 
    data-selectreq={{field.rules.selectreq}} 
    data-showhide={{field.rules.showhide}}
>
    <option value="" selected>Please select...</option> 
    <option ng-if="field.type=='select'"
        value={{option.id}} 
        ng-repeat="option in cache[field.relationshipURL] | orderBy:'name || firstName'" 
        ng-selected="formData[field.name] == option.id">
            {{option.name || option.firstName}}
    </option>
    <option ng-if="field.type=='select_name'"
        value={{option.name}} 
        ng-repeat="option in cache[field.relationshipURL] | orderBy:'name'"
        ng-selected="formData[field.name] == option.name" >
            {{option.name}}
    </option>
    <option ng-if="field.type=='select_static_id'"
        value={{option.id}} 
        ng-repeat="option in cache[field.relationshipURL] | orderBy:'name'"
        ng-selected="formData[field.name] == option.id" >
            {{option.name}}
    </option>
    <option ng-if="field.type=='select_static_name'"
        value={{option.name}} 
        ng-repeat="option in cache[field.relationshipURL] | orderBy:'name'"
        ng-selected="formData[field.name] == option.name">
            {{option.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Thank you anyway @charlietfl very quick response.

Comment: this is really a candidate for a custom directive and just pass in array from controller to directive scope

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late for the answer, but I managed to make a working [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m2vbnuc3/) of what I hoped you tried to accomplish.

I factorized your code into a single select and added another select to show you how to display either only one, or all of them.

```
<div>
        <select ng-model="selector">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="">Show everything</option>
            <option ng-repeat="option in Options" value="{{option.type}}">{{option.type}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
   <div ng-repeat="option in Options"  ng-show="$parent.selector == option.type || $parent.selector == ''">
    {{option.type}}
    <select>
        <option ng-repeat="choice in option.choices" value="{{choice}}">{{choice}}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

And the data :

```
$scope.Options = [
{type:"id", choices:["0", "1", "2"]},
{type:"name", choices:["John", "Doe", "Smith"]},
{type:"static_id", choices:["3", "4", "5"]},
{type:"static_name", choices:["Static 1", "Static 2", "Static 3"]},
];
```